Casbin.net Breaking changes while migrating from V1.13.0 to V2.9.1 - GetModel and GetPolicy
I am trying to migrate Casbin.net package from V1.13.0 to V2.9.1. I was validating my permission setup with this function in the earlier version.
private bool IsValidPermissionPolicySetup(string model, string policy)
        {
            CustomEnforcer enforcer = new CustomEnforcer(model, policy);
            int model_count = enforcer.GetModel().Model.Count;
            if (enforcer.GetPolicy().Any(x => x.Count != model_count))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (enforcer.GetPolicy().Any(x => x[model_count - 1] != "allow" && x[model_count - 1] != "deny"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

in the wiki, it says that enforcer.GetModel() is now replaced by enforcer.Model. but I couldn't find a way to get this count as the IModel interface doesn't explicitly have any property. Also, the wiki doesn't mention the alternative of enforcer.GetPolicy() so not sure how to convert the above function to the latest version. Can someone help here?
